# Plotly with filter checkboxes is trimmed off on left edge in HTML output

Tags: r, plotly, quarto

I'm trying to create a scatter plot with responsive data filter check boxes. When knitting to HTML, the left edge trims off. Neither of the following codes seem to work:

- rmarkdown chunk options: `{r, fig.width=, fig.height=}`
- quarto render options: `#| fig-width:` & `#| fig-height:`
- ggplotly: `ggplotly(width=, height=)`
- plotly layout: `ggplotly() %>% layout(width=, height=)`
- YAML: `fig-responsive: false`

Here's an example of the issue with the penguins data set for reproducibility:

````
---
format:
  html: 
    grid:
      sidebar-width: 300px
      body-width: 900px
      margin-width: 300px
      gutter-width: 1.5rem
fig-responsive: false
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---


```{r, label=packages, results='hide', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(knitr)
library(crosstalk)
```

```{r, label=data, echo=FALSE}
library(palmerpenguins)
df <- penguins 
df <- drop_na(penguins)
```

## INDIVIDUAL PLOT

```{r, label=individual_plot, echo=FALSE}

gg <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = bill_length_mm, y = bill_depth_mm, color = species)) +
  geom_jitter()

gg 
```

## PLOT W FILTER

```{r, label=plot_w_filter, echo=FALSE}
#Create new shared data for crosstalk library
shared_data <- df %>% 
  select(bill_depth_mm, bill_length_mm, species) %>%  
  SharedData$new()

#Create scatter plotly column
plty <- shared_data %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~bill_length_mm, y = ~bill_depth_mm, color = ~species, type="scatter", mode="markers") 

#Combine filter(left) with scatter plotly (right)
flt_pltl <-bscols(widths = c(2,10), #<-(col1,col2) widths
       list(
            filter_checkbox(id = "species", label = "Species", sharedData = shared_data, group = ~species)),plty)

flt_pltl
```
````

Here are the knitter plot outputs:

[image: gg]

[image: flt_pltl]

However, it appears perfectly fine when rendered in the RStudio console output viewer

[image: RStudio console output viewer]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think the simplest approach so that only what you want fixed is a bit of inline CSS. I see two issues, the text size is odd in comparison to the plot. Additionally, the text overflow is hidden. Place this between chunks as if it were text-`<style>#species {font-size: .7em; padding: 2em;}</style>`. I put it between the last two chunks, but I don't think it matters where you put it.